# Version 2.0 (adding Queries now)

Tags: java, loops, collections

I am writing a program that will read a file and extract the data for each student. I did this successfully with a while loop and input.next(). However, I need to pass the variables into a collection to record each students data, so for each loop I want to add the 4 variables (id, first, last, year) to the collection again. I should note that the collection has to be in a different class and that I will have to be able to search through this collection to find, for example, all students graduating this year. 
If anyone could point me in the right direct in regard to storing the variables in a collection, which is in a different class, for each loop. 
I know this is a basic question but I am very new to Java so I appreciate everyone’s help!

The first class is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

  public class ProcessRecords {

   public static void AskUser() 
   throws Exception {
      Scanner preference = new Scanner(System.in);
      //Creating a new scanner will allow us to gather user input

    boolean flag=true; 
    //I will use this for my while loop

    while (flag) {
        System.out.println("What type of Search would you like to run?\n 1)Search for all students\n 2) Search for students graduating in a specific year\n 3)Search for students whose last name begins with a certain string\n");
        int searchType=preference.nextInt();
        //This variable will store what type of query the user would like to run

        switch(searchType) {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Gathering Records for all students\n");
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return all students in the colletion
            case 2
            System.out.println("What graduation year would you like to search for? \n");
            String yearsearch=preference.next();
            //Call Query Method to return students who are graduating in the specified year
            //Pass the "yearsearch" variable to the Query class to run the search
            case 3:
            System.out.println("What string would you like to search for? \n");
            String lstsearch=preference.next();
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return students who have the string in their last name
            //I need to pass the "lstsearch" variable to the Query class to search through last   names                

        }
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 throws Exception
 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
    //This will import the file
    input.nextLine();
    //This will skip the headers in the file
    System.out.println("Processing file now...");
    //Let the user know that the file is being processed
    int id;
    String last;
    String first;
    int year;
    int i=1;
    // Declare variables that we will extract from the file

    //Now we will being processing the file with a while loop

    List<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        id=input.nextInt();
        last=input.next();
        first=input.next();
        year=input.nextInt();
        StudentRecord record = new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year);
        studentRecords.add(record);
        System.out.println(id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println(" You have successfully read and printed from the file!");
    for (StudentRecord s : studentRecords)
        System.out.println(s.toString());
}
}
```

The next Class is

```
   public class StudentRecord{
   public int id;
   public String last;
   public String first;
   public int year;

  public StudentRecord(int d, String lt, String ft, int yr){
      id=d;
      last=lt;
      first=ft;
      year=yr;
  }

   public String toString()
   {
       return id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year;
   } 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you created a class with the attributes you need to store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second class:

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    public int id;
    public String last;
    public String first;
    public int year;

    public StudentRecord(int d, String lt, String ft, int yr)
    {
        id=d;
        last=lt;
        first=ft;
        year=yr;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year;
    } 
}
```

The method is called constructor and you can create instances of this class using it.

In your second class, while running through the loop, you can create new StudentRecord object with actual values for each entry by passing parameters to the constructor:

```
    List<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        id=input.nextInt();
        last=input.next();
        first=input.next();
        year=input.nextInt();
        StudentRecord record = new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year);
        studentRecords.Add(record);
        System.out.println(id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year + "\n");

    }
```

The ArrayList will serve you as a storage of all StudentRecord objects.

If you override the toString method of your StudentRecord object (as I did above), you can print all student records to the console in a loop:

```
for (StudentRecord s : studentRecords)
    System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can print to the screen all of the elements in the Arraylist?

Comment: Last question, in another new class, for example public class Query, how could I search through the List array for say students graduating in 2014 and then print those results to the screen? Is this possible? If you could help me with just figuring out how to search through the List array for a specific graduation year and print those results, I am sure I can do the rest of them. 

I have updated my code in the edit above.
In the ProcessRecords class I will ask the user what type of query he/she would like to run. Each type of  query will correspond to a number in. (See next Comment)

Comment: I will use a Switch/case to determine what type of query he/she wants to run.Then I will pass that response (i.e. 1,2,3) to the query class to perform the search and print the results to the screen.
Thank you so much for your help, being that I am so new to programming in general it is such a large help!

Comment: You should get used to search and google more. The Internet is full of examples and tutorials. In this case, you can use a simple condition in for cycle: if (s.year == 2014) then ...

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with making an ArrayList of StudentRecord objects?

```
public class StudentRecord {
    public int id;
    public String last;
    public String first;
    public int year;

    public StudentRecord(int id, String last, String first, int year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.last = last;
        this.first = first;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Then right after you grab the values from a file:

```
ArrayList<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();

//...

id = input.nextInt();
last = input.next();
first = input.next();
year = input.nextInt();

studentRecords.add(new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year));

//...
```